# Passar dados Ajax (X-Editable) via $_POST

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentando receber dados de um formulário, onde alguns campos utilizo Ajax mais especificamente o plugin `X-Editable`.

Ao recepcionar na minha pagina PHP aparece a mensagem de erro abaixo.

HTML:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="termo8" action="procTermo.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#capaTermo8">08. Termo Abertura</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="capaTermo8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Serial:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SerialTermo8" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="well text-justify well-sm">
                            Aos <a href='#' id='diaTermo8'>28</a> dias do mês de <a href='#' id='mesTermo8'>Setembro</a> de <a href='#' id='anoTermo8'>2015</a>, 
                            nesta cidade de <a href='#' id='cidadeTermo8'>CIDADE</a> – <a href='#' id='estadoTermo8'>UF</a>, realizo a abertura deste edital.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cleanfix"></div>
                    <button class="btn btn-inverse" name="btnGerar" value="gerar8">Gerar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

O Funcionamento do X-Editable, quando eu clico em cima de algum desses link ele abre um popover para eu poder editar os dados que já estão pré estabelecidos entre `<a>`, ao finalizar clico em OK ai substitui o valor.

Ajax (X-Editable):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
$.fn.editable.defaults.send = "always";
$.fn.editable.defaults.url = "procTermo.php";
$.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "POST"};
$('#diaTermo8').editable({type:'text',title: 'Informe o dia'});
$('#mesTermo8').editable({type:'text',title: 'Informe o mes'});
$('#anoTermo8').editable({type:'text',title: 'Informe o ano'}); 
$('#cidadeTermo8').editable({type:'text',title: 'Informe a Cidade'});       
$('#estadoTermo8').editable({type:'text',title: 'Informe o estado'});               
});</script>
```

PHP (procTermo.php):

```
    switch ($_POST['btnGerar']) {
        case 'gerar8':

    $varMesTermo8 = $_POST['mesTermo8'];
    $varDiaTermo8 = $_POST['diaTermo8'];
    $varAnoTermo8 = $_POST['anoTermo8'];
    $varCidadeTermo8 = $_POST['cidadeTermo8'];
    $varEstadoTermo8 = $_POST['estadoTermo8'];
break;
}
```

Quando eu dou `echo` em qualquer uma destas variavéis, retorna o erro abaixo.

Erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: mesTermo8, diaTermo8 (Todas mesmo erro) in /var/www/sistema/procTermo.php

E no `print_r($_POST)`, não traz nenhum dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o **X-Editable**, envia os parâmetros como array associativa contendo 3 valores, sendo que vai passar a possuir também 3 índices diferentes para cada um destes valores, veja este exemplo abaixo, de como chegam os valores passados por uma requisição feita pelo X-Editable.

> Array ( [name] => nome [value] => Valor_de_deste [pk] => 1 )

Seguidamente:

- name - corresponde ao valor passado em `name` nas configurações da requisição.
- value - será o valor do campo editado
- pk - é também inicializado na primeira configuração.

Aqui vai uma possível solução para este problema:

```
$_POST[isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : NULL] = isset($_POST["value"]) ? $_POST["value"] : NULL;
// Isto seria a forma encurtada, talvez meio embaraçada, mas fica simplicida no script.
```

Ou ainda esta forma aqui, escrita sobre blocos de múltiplas linhas:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        if(isset($_POST["value"])){
            $_POST[$_POST["name"]] = $_POST["value"];    
        }    
    }    
} else {
    $_POST = NULL;    
}
```

Ambos iriam funcionar bem, e como eu disse, isso pode ser uma das várias soluções, se é a mais recomendada, isso já eu não sei, até porque nunca antes utilizei esse *plugin* antes.

Depois de escreveres/copiares um destes códigos para o teu script, poderás simplesmente ler as variáveis `$_POST` da forma habitual, sem ter de indicar mais de uma posição da array.

echo $_POST["mesTermo8"]; // Vai retornar o valor nela contido.

Como eu já disse, nunca antes utilizei o *plugin* em referência, caso aches que podes melhorar ou contornar esse `hack` aí, sinta-se à vontade.

## Exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Edição em linha
                $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
                // Definir o tipo de passagem, por omissão é POST
                // colocar novamente como eu fiz é praticamente forçar
                // Ainda assim não afecta em nada
                $.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "POST"};
                // Um único campo, vai ser editado neste exemplo.
                $('#nome').editable({
                    type: 'text',
                    pk: 1,
                    nome: 'nome',
                    url: 'editar.php',
                    title: 'Digite o novo nome',
                    /*
                     * Caso queiras confirmas se realmente teve efeito
                     * Ou ainda se quiseres saber o que o PHP retornou
                     * Utiliza-se o "success" para isto
                     *
                    success: function(retorno_do_php, novo_valor){
                        $("#stat").html("Retorno do PHP: " + retorno_do_php + "<br/> Novo valor: " + novo_valor + "<br/>");
                    }*/
                    
                });
                
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <!-- Se quiseres adicionar alguma mensagem retornada pelo script PHP
         Descomenta esta tag
    <div id="stat"></div>
    !-->
    Nome: <a href="#" id="nome">Nome</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
// Configuração
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        if(isset($_POST["value"])){
            $_POST[$_POST["name"]] = $_POST["value"];    
        }    
    }    
} else {
    $_POST = NULL;    
}

// variavel $nome recebendo o valor de $_POST normalmente
$nome = $_POST["nome"];

// Ficheiro se quer escrever
$filename = 'database.txt';

// Condições para escrever no ficheiro selecionado
// Exemplo tirado da página do php.net > fputs
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    $count = file('database.txt'); 
    $fp = fopen("database.txt", "w");
    fputs ($fp, $nome ."\r\n");
    fclose ($fp);
} 

else 
{
    $fh = fopen("database.txt", "w");
    if($fh==false)
    die("Sem permisao no diretorio");
    fputs ($fh, $nome ."\r\n");
    fclose ($fh);
    $count = file('database.txt'); 
}
```

---

## Referências

[X-Editable - vitalets](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)

Comment: Olá Edilson, ótima explicação. Porem mesmo com os exemplos citados acima, não consegui nenhum valor no meu array $_POST, pelo pouco que entendo, parece que na hora de eu dar submit no meu formulario, todos os outros valores são enviados, porem só o que esta no Ajax não envia, isso verificando com print_r($_POST)

Comment: Edita a tua pergunta, e acrescenta mais detalhes ao teu script, ou então completa-o, para que eu possa ver melhor como está, ou então armazena-o no _pastebin_.

Comment: Vê se ficou mais claro Edilson.

Comment: Aí está, um exemplo para auxiliar a explicação.